# Zend Framework: Inserting calls to View Helpers into Javascript code

Tags: javascript, ajax, zend-framework

I'm developing a web application, where I use jQuery to make Ajax calls to the server.

I'm using the `url` view helper to insert the URL to be called. The code inside my view scripts looks like the following:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'myaction', 'controller' => 'mycontroller'), null, true); ?>",
        dataType: "html",
        data: { id: myId, format: 'xml' },
        beforeSend: function() {
            // Show pseudoprogress
        },
        success: function(html) {
            // Process response
        },
        error: function() {
            // Show an error message
        }
    });
```

The system is working fine, but because of this approach I can't extract the Javascript code to separate files, because I always need to run it through the PHP interpreter first.

I wonder if there is a better way to do it, so that I can keep the Javascript code as "PHP-clean" as possible (and eventually, in separate files).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can store data in JSON format and then you can use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide the url in a hidden input field or any other hidden markup element you like and get it from there with jQuery.

Example:

In the view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myActionUrl" value="<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'myaction', 'controller' => 'mycontroller'), null, true); ?>" />
```

In the javascript:

```
url : $('#myActionUrl').val(),
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var url = "<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'myaction', 'controller' => 'mycontroller'), null, true); ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: It's the same as my solution but creates clutter outside the js files.

Comment: if he use an form sure, but then he could altough use:  $("#myForm").attr('action');  or?

Comment: The point is not whether or not he uses a form. As I wrote, my solution works with any hidden element (form or not). The difference is that your solution, which also works, needs additional script tags in the <head> while mine doesn't.

Comment: Ok :-) Thanxs for the details!